# How to write a rolling forecast with xreg but without re-estimation in R?

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, arima

I am hoping to write a rolling window Multi-step forecast without re-estimation (I instead want to keep using an ARIMA(1,0,0) model the entire time) and implement an xreg into this.

I make use of the code from Rob Hyndam  who has the following code:

```
h <- 5
train <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)
test <- window(hsales,start=1990)
n <- length(test) - h + 1
fit <- auto.arima(train)
fc <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
for(i in 1:n)
{  
  x <- window(hsales, end=1989.99 + (i-1)/12)
  refit <- Arima(x, model=fit)
  fc[i] <- forecast(refit, h=h)$mean[h]
}
```

I have read a number of different posts but many utilise a re-estimation of the model when also implementing an xreg  and when trying to solve the issue I frequently ran in to the problem of the length of my xreg not matching in the fit line.

Thus I tried to solve my issue with this code:

```
h <- 5
train <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)
test <- window(hsales,start=1990)
xregtrain <-window(hsales, end=1989.99)
n <- length(test) - h + 1
fit <- arima(train, order= c(1,0,0), xreg = xregtrain)
fc <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
for(i in 1:n)
{  
  x <- window(hsales, end=1989.99+ (i-1)/12)
  y<- window(hsales, end=1989.99 + (i-1)/12)
  refit <- Arima(x, order=c(1,0,0), xreg=y)
  fc[i] <- forecast(refit, h=h, xreg=y)$mean[h]
}
```

This should update the length of xreg to match the length of hsales at each new forecast and appears to work, however I was hoping someone could tell me how I can check that this is updating the values for xreg at each new forecast or perhaps someone with a greater understanding can confirm that it is doing what I want it to do.

My final question is; how to do i take the forecasted values from this and analyse the forecasting ability of this model for example how do I compute MAPE for this forecast ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your current code won't work because you are regressing a series against itself (`xreg` is the same as the time series you are modelling). Here is some code that does what you want using a randomly generated xreg for illustration purposes.

```
library(fpp2)

h <- 5
train <- window(hsales, end = c(1989, 12))
test <- window(hsales, start = 1990)
xreg <- hsales * rnorm(length(hsales))
xregtrain <- window(xreg, end = c(1989, 12))
fit <- Arima(train, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = xregtrain)
n <- length(test) - h + 1
fc <- ts(numeric(n), start=c(1990, h), frequency = 12)
for (i in seq(n)) {
  y <- window(hsales, end = c(1990, i - 1))
  x <- window(xreg, end = c(1990, i - 1))
  refit <- Arima(y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = x)
  fc[i] <- forecast(refit, h = h, xreg = x)$mean[h]
}
accuracy(fc, test)
```

The `accuracy()` function will compute the MAPE and other forecast accuracy measures.

Comment: Thank you for the help! If I wanted to make this into a rolling window forecast how would I do this ?

Comment: Add a start date to the windows in the loop

Comment: Hi Rob, 

Thank you for the help.

 If for example I wanted a rolling window to last 10 periods (equal to h=10) I tried to do the following in the loop; 

for (i in seq(n))

 { y <- window(hsales, start=c(1990, i-10), end = c(1990, i - 1)) 
x <- window(xreg, start=c(1990, i-10), end = c(1990, i - 1)) 
refit <- Arima(y, order = c(1, 0, 0), xreg = x) 
fc[i] <- forecast(refit, h = h, xreg = x)$mean[h] 
}

However, I get the error : "Error in c(1990,i-10): object not interpretable as a factor"

Where have I gone wrong here ?

Thanks,

James